# way to pin point failed item in a chunk during write in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

What are the ways to log exact item which failed during writing a chunk of say 10 items size ?

Is there a way to catch it in onWriteError method of ItemWriteListener ? 
Is it possible to know this by extending ItemWriter interface ?

Thanks and Regards,
Nik

Answer (score 1):

you could configure [skip logic](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#configuringSkip) with Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2.147.483.647

```
<step id="step1">
   <tasklet>
      <chunk reader="flatFileItemReader" writer="itemWriter" 
             commit-interval="10" skip-limit="2147483647">
         <skippable-exception-classes>
            <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>
         </skippable-exception-classes>
      </chunk>
   </tasklet>
   <listeners>
        <listener ref="customSkipListener" />
   </listeners>
</step>
```

and use a [skip listener](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#skipListener) (see the annotations there too) to log bad items during writing

if your writer is already a custom implementation, it could be extended to be a Listener which responds to OnSkipInWrite only, just add method with @OnSkipInWrite and register the writer as listener (*)

(*) beware - if the writer is a stream too, do not register as listener, streams are automatically registered as (step)listeners

Comment: Hello Michael.. Thanks for your reply.. that answers my query.. Can you please check my previous post as well.. the query regarding skip during write...  thanks.. nik