# Spring Batch: onWriteError in ItemWriteListener won't be reached on org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException when implementing writer in step

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to capture items that have failed to be inserted into database due to unique key violation. After 'everywhere' research this is discouragingly starting to feel like unfixed bug or something. I honestly need a helpful clarification.

Edit: Visited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772318/way-to-pin-point-failed-item-in-a-chunk-during-write-in-spring-batch) to have skipped exceptions captured using `@OnSkipInWrite` and this is either not clear enough or just wont work.

```
@Bean
public PersonFailureLoggerListener loggerListener() {
    return new PersonFailureLoggerListener();
}

@Bean
public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) throws MalformedURLException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(fileVerificationSkipper())
            .processor(itemProcessor())
            .writer(writer)
            //.listener(new PersonWriteListener())
            .listener(loggerListener().asItemProcessListener())
            .build();
}
```

**Item listener support:**

```
@Component
public class PersonFailureLoggerListener extends ItemListenerSupport<Person, Person> {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Person.class.getSimpleName().concat(".error"));

@Override
public void afterProcess(Person i, Person o) {
    LOG.info("before: {}, after: {}", i.toString(), o.toString());
}

@Override
public void onWriteError(Exception excptn, List<? extends Person> list) {
    LOG.debug("list[{}] threw write exception", list.size(), excptn);
}

@Override
public void onReadError(Exception excptn) {
    LOG.debug("encountered error on read", excptn);
}

public ItemProcessListener<Person, Person> asItemProcessListener() {
    return this;
}
}
```

**Update on** `PersonFailureLoggerListener`:

```
@OnSkipInWrite
public void onSkipInWrite( Person skippedItem, Exception exception ){
    LOG.debug("skipped person: {}", skippedItem.toString());
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [way to pin point failed item in a chunk during write in spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772318/way-to-pin-point-failed-item-in-a-chunk-during-write-in-spring-batch)

Comment: awesome, seems like it, lemme check it out

Comment: Kindly see my update

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: Visited here to have skipped exceptions captured using @OnSkipInWrite and this is either not clear enough or just wont work.

The answer suggests to use a `SkipListener` but you are registering a `ItemProcessListener` here:

```
.listener(loggerListener().asItemProcessListener())
```

Those are two different listeners which are called at different points in the step lifecycle. To listen to skipped items, you should register a `SkipListener`:

```
class MySkipListener extends SkipListenerSupport {
    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(Object item, Throwable t) {
        // TODO do something with skipped items
    }
}

@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            // .. step config
            .listener(new MySkipListener())
            .build();
}
```